# How it's possible that root can use somebody else private key to login?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

User ``alice'' has public key access to server example.com. So he can do:

```
ssh root@example.com
```

without pwd.

Now on the same local machine root can do the same, i.e. he can access the remote machine without pwd. But I did not even generate a key pair for root. So it looks like root is using alice's private key to login to remote server. How can this happen? Bug, or misconfiguration, or a misunderstanding on my side?

Of course root has access to alice's id_rsa file but it is weird that it is using that file automatically.

Comment: How does root log in to the local compuer? If she logs in as "alice" and than changes identity, depending on the mechanism used to raise privileges it is possible that that key still gets used.

Comment: Hello, no root does not change identity. It is just plain root, and also without any public key inside his home, i.e. there is no such file: /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Comment: Try `ssh -v root@example.com` from both `alice` and `root`, and examine the authentication mechanisms that come into play. Also, try `ssh-add -l` as both users and examine the keys actually added to the SSH agent. Also, examine the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable in both users' shells, just to make sure they're not using the same agent for some reason.

Comment: It shows that root is using alice@localhost.localdomain, like this: debug1: Offering RSA public key: alice@localhost.localdomain But I already said that. The question is not that. The question is: Why does it use alice's public key. It is non sense. By the way, alice does not have sudo rights. And, if I rename alice's public key, root can no longer login to remote server.

Comment: Anyway, I guess root is looking for every users' keys on the system. Because if I remove alice's keys, (or even if I remove the .pub extension) root can no longer login. So it looks like root is using other people's keys. But it does not make any sense.

Comment: In your case there's a misunderstanding of key authentication. Though the scheme is called "public key authentication", in fact it's the private key which is used for authentication and which must be present. If your root has access only to .pub[lic key] file, then he can do nothing - he doesn't have a private key.

Comment: You are right, I understand that. It should be written "root has access to id_rsa" instead. You are correct! But still it doesn't explain the issue.

Comment: Personally I would **NOT** allow anybody to `ssh` into a computer as root. Add a little extra protection by ensuring that they log into your machine with a known username. They can then `su` as necessary. It also has the advantage that people get into the habit of always logging in as `root`. Do their tasks. Bit better if they get into the habit of just changing into `root` when necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but what is the relation of this to the question?

Comment: Please post the `ssh -v` output on pastebin or similar.

Comment: When you say that root can do the same, are you actually logging in as root (`sudo -i`) or are you running `sudo ssh root@example.com` when logged in as Alice?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Alice's identity file is configured for the machine.  Look in `/etc/ssh_config` and you should find an entry for an Identity file that points to Alice's id_rsa file.  It should look something like this:

```
IdentityFile ~Alice/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If this is true, this means that any user on Alice's machine can ssh as root to the example.com server.  To prevent this, comment out or remove this line from the ssh_config.

Comment: I guess it is ``/etc/ssh/ssh_config'' at least in my distro. In any case, there is no such entry in that file. It points to root's ~/.ssh but it is commented out. So not effective.

Comment: Take a look at the files in `/etc/ssh/`.  Are any of them symbolic links to Alice's file?

Comment: No. [required to write 12 more chars ...]

Comment: What does the `sshd_config` on the example.com server look like?  Also, can any other users on Alice's box ssh as root to example.com?

Comment: Nothing special in sshd_config. What info are you asking? Other users on the local machine cannot login to remote by the above method. As it should.

Comment: If other users can't login to the remote server the same way then the sshd daemon is probably not misconfigured on the example.com server.  Let's go back to the root user on Alice's machine.  What is the home dir of the root user according to `/etc/passwd`?  if you do a `ls -al ~root` what do you see?

Comment: One more thing to check is if the root user has an rhosts file on example.com and if the `sshd_config` on that machine is configured to use it.

Comment: Sorry, do a `ls -al ~root/.ssh` on Alice's box.  What files do you see?

Comment: Home dir is /root and /root/.ssh is empty. As was stated in the question. There is no rhosts on the remote machine.

Answer (score -1):

Misunderstanding I think. User 'Alice' has root privileges. That's why both 'Alice' and 'root' can ssh to example.com as root - both are sharing the same user group with root privileges. Check GID.

Comment: First, user alice does not have sudo privileges here. Second, even if he did, it would be a weird thing that root uses alice's id_rsa.pub.

Comment: 'Alice' is using 'root' account to ssh to the server. In other words, authorized_keys on server contains a key generated for 'root' user.

Comment: Your answer does not make sense unless you explicitly answer: IS the root user, for example, scanning other users' .ssh directories, and then using each one, trying to log in until he finds a valid key? Otherwise how can he make use of alice's key? Your answer does not say anything.

Comment: I have answered your question already... But to say it more clearly: no it is NOT possible.

Comment: What is ``not possible''? Sorry I don't understand anything from your sentences. Appreciate your answer though. Good luck!

Comment: It is not possible that 'root' user uses any of public key defined for different user accounts.